# Is there any free Telerik ASP.NET MVC extensions version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am going to develop website using ASP.NET MVC 4. I'd like to take advantage of rich Telerik extensions. I there any free version of it for ASP.NET MVC?

First of all I need grids functionallity. Can you suggest any alternative solutions?

Comment: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid

Comment: Thanks! This lib is just incredible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the grid of jQuery.

[Jquery grid example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/230353/An-Example-to-Use-jQuery-Grid-Plugin-in-MVC-Part-1)